# Fluid Mechanics (compressible flow question)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I am a grader for a fluid mechanics class, and have come across a problem that I don't understand the answer to, and I was hoping someone could explain it to me. I've quoted the question below.

> Consider compressible flow through the converging nozzle below, that has a low velocity at the inlet and a sonic velocity (Ma=1) at the exit. the nozzle exit diameter is reduced by half while the inlet temperature and pressure are maintained the same. the nozzle exit velocity will:
>
> - a) remain the same
> - b) double
> - c) quadruple
> - d) go down by 1/4th
> - e) go
>   down by half

(The included picture is rather useless, it just shows two nozzles one with a smaller opening at one end. I'd take the effort of posting it if it were relevant)

According to the solutions I have, the answer is supposedly `a) remain the same` but I don't understand why. Based on the continuity equation, shouldn't it be `c) quadruple`? Or does that assume it is an incompressible fluid?

Comment: If the exit velocity is sonic for the bigger nozzle you have choked flow for both nozzles. Apparently, you don't understand the basics of *compressible* flow through a nozzle (see any textbook). The continuity equation is irrelevant since the mass flow through the two nozzles will be different.

Comment: Incompressible fluid and a compressible (sonic) flow are in no way compatible! Furthermore @alephzero is right: A simple converging nozzle can't reach higher speeds than sonic as sub- and supersonic flow behave differently (area Mach number relation http://www.potto.org/gasDynamics/node82.html). You will need a special convergent-divergent nozzle, a so called Laval nozzle, to get to supersonic flow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle Using a normal convergent nozzle will result in a choked flow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choked_flow Please read it up as this is really essential!